# Dictionary application for Data Structures

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am here seeking help. more or less a point in the right direction as I dont even know where to start. My professor has thrown a large project on me to complete over the course of the month and I just dont know where to start.

This is the project:

"The Dictionary Application project in java performs translation from English to the language of your choice. Translation symbol tables are to be given for English words with corresponding entries for foreign words. The implementation should be based on any binary search trees presented in the lectures. The project comprises of the following stages:

Build a tree  using  insertion (put() method) of information and searches. The test client must build a tree storing the information of the ~50 popular English words - the keys in the nodes and values are corresponding translations. Then look for translation of the given English word. Use first argument as file of comma-separated key-value pairs on the command line to read data from standard input. The second argument is a search English word for translation.

Implement traversal method of the tree result of which will be the printed content.

Implement the extract (delete() ) method in binary search tree. This method is similar to search by key and returning the corresponding value, but it removes the node from the tree. Modify all the necessary methods to consider the deletion (when the node is added to the tree, the size() increases,  extract  - decreases the size() of the tree). "

I do not want someone to just "do my homework" for me, I would rather your advice and point in right direction.

I'm aiming to start off with the Binary Search Tree but from there I get stuck.

Comment: Do you want binarysearchtree or redblack binary search trees.?

Comment: This is a video of binary search trees and i'm recommending you because it's based of book by Robert sedgewick https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX4WQ8l_NA8 and the book is here , https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/

Comment: BinarySearchTree

Comment: It's a great source and you will love his way of explaining thigs :) good luck

Comment: So you've already covered binary search trees in your course? Have you covered reading data from a file into a class? Rather than throwing up your hands and saying, "I don't know where to start," sit down and think a bit. Write steps, in English (or your preferred human language) describing what has to be done, step by step. Then start at the beginning.